# Easiest way of creating a timer in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, timer

Im trying to make a timer for a game, and I'm stuck atm.
This is my code so far. I made a new activity for the intent, cause I read somewhere that's one way to do it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //Timer timer = new Timer();
        //task = new TimerTask() {

            Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);        
            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v){

                    startActivity(new Intent("com.loltimer.Timer"));
                }
            });
      };  
}
```

When I press the first button I want to have a timer that goes from 5minutes down to 0. And at 0 I want a sound to be played. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Has got to be the Android count down timer class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 0):

Timing operations are best handled by a `Handler` in Android.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

You can wrap the operation you want to run in the future as a `Runnable` and pass it to `postDelayed()`.  If the operation needs to run repeatedly on that interval, you can call `postDelayed()` at the end of the `Runnable` to schedule the next run.

`CountdownTimer` can also be useful if you need to run some code a finite number of times on a regular interval.  This class is actually just a thin wrapper around `Handler`.